# Using a timer to trigger an event in windows metro with C++

Tags: c++, windows, timer, microsoft-metro

So I'm developing an application that takes a picture after a countdown is complete. I've worked with the win32 timer in windows 7, but I have no clue on how to apply it in windows metro. I need some  help or some sample code in c++ pertaining to how to trigger an event after a set amount of time expires. 
Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++,  declare the DispatcherTimer, and register one event handler on it.

DispatcherTimer class - http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

Sample code:

```
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;
using namespace Windows::Foundation;


void Application1::MainPage::Button_Click(Platform::Object^ sender, Windows::UI::Xaml::RoutedEventArgs^ e)
{
    DispatcherTimer^ timer = ref new DispatcherTimer;
    timer->Tick += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::EventHandler(this, &Application1::MainPage::DispatcherTimer_Tick);
    TimeSpan t;
    t.Duration=1000;
    timer->Interval = t;
    timer->Start();
}

void Application1::MainPage::DispatcherTimer_Tick(Platform::Object^ sender, Platform::Object^ e)
{
   // Put TO DO stuff here...
}
```

Comment: I'm having issues with the line 'timer->Tick += ref new Windows::UI::Xaml::EventHandler(this, &Application1::MainPage::DispatcherTimer_Tick); the Compiler doesn't recognize "windows::ui::xaml::eventhandler" as a type

Comment: The type of the event is `Windows::Foundation::EventHandler<Platform::Object^>^`.

Comment: Now I'm getting  `usage requires Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer::Tick' to be a data member`

Comment: * had changed the += to =. Thanks everyone for their help !!

Answer (score 0):

> [`Windows::UI::Xaml::DispatcherTimer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.dispatchertimer.aspx)

The documentation includes an example of its use.  The example is in C#, but it should be straightforward to translate it into C++/CX.

Comment: unfortunately translating this into C# is difficult because DateTimeOffset apparently doesn't exist in the c++ version of the library.

Comment: DateTimeOffset is Windows::Foundation::DateTime in C++